# Как развернуть вложенный блок на весь экран по ширине?

Tags: css

Как сделать, что бы зеленый блок развернулся на весь экран по ширине, при условии что его нельзя менять его вложенность относительно того блока (желтого) где он находится?

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: auto; background-color: yellow;">
<div style="height: 120px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему не использовать     position: absolute; для зелёного ? другой возможности нет, если он внутри блока с установленой шириной

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: auto; background-color: yellow;">
<div style="position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0;height: 120px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```