# Как развернуть вложенный блок на вессь экран по ширине?

Tags: css

Как сделать, чтобы зеленый блок развернулся на весь экран по ширине, при условии, что его нельзя менять его вложенность относительно того блока (желтого) где он находится?

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: auto; background-color: yellow;">
<div style="height: 120px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `style="position: absolute; width:100%; left: 0; ... "?` - не подойдёт?

Comment: этот вопрос дубликат, наверно случайно создали клон первого вопроса.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788215/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5

Comment: есть величины vh и vw которые являются 1% от высоты экрана и 1% от ширины соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть возможность вынести див из потока, то можно сделать через абсолютное позиционирование:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div style="
width: 100px; 
height: 300px; 
margin: auto; 
background-color: yellow;">
  <div style="
  height: 120px; 
  background-color: green;  
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `jQuery`, при этом блок не вылетает из потока:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  beyondParents($('.my'))
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  beyondParents($('.my'))
});

function beyondParents(div) {
  let outerWidth = $(window).width();
  let itemPosition = div.offset().left;
  div.css({
    "margin-left": "-" + itemPosition + "px",
    "width": outerWidth + "px"
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 300px; margin: auto; background-color: yellow;">
  <div class="my" style="height: 120px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: в вопросе нет метки javascript с помощью скрипта решение не подходит

Comment: @perfect отсутствие метки не исключает возможность использования скриптов. Да, ради такого вряд ли стоит использовать js, однако случаи бывают разные. Не подходит вам, подойдет возможно кому-то другому. Зато с помощью этого способа можно оставить блок в потоке.